# In Android studio failed to complete Gradle execution, a fatal exception is occured?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, path

```
package com.example.sachin.practices;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.com"));
        startActivity(i);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the simple code i am going to execute but i getting the error, failed to complete gradle execution, while Executing the the log message like this,

Waiting for device.
Target device: asus-asus_t00j-EAAZCY30C637
Uploading file local path: C:\Users\Sachin\AndroidStudioProjects\Practic\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.sachin.practices
Local path doesn't exist.

I am confused what is the exact problem this is due to Gradle or anything else.

Comment: local path does not exists check this path `C:\Users\Sachin\AndroidStudioProjects\Practic\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk` wheather APK exists or not

Comment: remove app in device real.

Comment: What does your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: Before executing the project make sure build.gradle is valid, and if the gradle file modified then synchronize the project to apply the modifications.

Comment: while  synchoronize the project, i am getting the following error.Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the following fix worked for me:

In Android Studio go to..

File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Input the following in the "Gradle VM options" box: -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m

Hit apply and Android Studio should build your project successfully.

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67946

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it was in one of the layout files. However the IDE wasn't able to detect it and the same error kept coming up.

I then ran gradlew assembleDebug from the command prompt.

1. Open cmd.

2.In cmd, navigate to your project directory where the outermost build.gradle file is present.

3. There type in 'gradlew assembleDebug'.

This will show you which file is the error exactly happening in and you can fix it. In my case it was a layout file.

Comment: I tried for this one but i getting an error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

Comment: Yep and a few line above that you'll find a line with this arrow '^' which indicates where your error is.
Fix it and it should work hopefully..